# Let $B$ be an open subset of $C$ and $\partial B $ denotes boundary of $B$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $B$ be an open subset of $C$ and $\partial B$ denote the boundary of $B$.Which of the following are correct?

(a) For every entire function $f$ ,we have $\partial(f(B)) \subset f(\partial B)$

(b) For every entire function $f$ and a bounded open set $B$ , we have       $\partial(f(B)) \subset f(\partial B)$

(c) For every function $f$ , we have $\partial(f(B)) = f(\partial B)$

(d) There exist an unbounded open subset $B$ of $C$ and an entire function $f$ such that $\partial(f(B)) \subset f(\partial B)$

From where I start, I can't understand.Please help something.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try $f(z) = 0$, $f(z) = z$, $f(z) = e^z$ and $B= \mathbb{C}$. This should let you answer (a), (c),  (d).

Comment: what is the boundary of $B$ here? and you give some particular examples ,how you ensure (a) and (c) are true for every entire function.I think some proof required but I can not start ....thank you@copper-hat

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\partial \mathbb{C}= \emptyset$.

(a) Take $f(z) = 0$, $B= \mathbb{C}$.

(b) See [Image under an entire function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1255850/27978).

(c) Take $f(z) = 0$, $B= \mathbb{C}$.

(d) Tahe $f(z) = z$, $B= \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: For (d) $\partial B=\emptyset$ $f(B)=\{f(z):z\in B\}=\{z:z\in B\}=\mathbb C$. which satisfy containment. How it is false?

Comment: It is not. Thanks for catching this. Will repair later  I think to

Comment: ...the link for (b) has an actual example.